# Where does St. Bernard say persons of opposite sex contemplating each other without sinful desires arising in them is greater than a resurrection?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, sexuality, saint

St. Francis Xavier Lasance, [*The Catholic Girl's Guide*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=2949) [p. 263](https://archive.org/details/catholicgirlsgui00lasa/page/263/mode/2up):

> 6. Remember also that maidens who boldly fix their gaze upon persons of the opposite sex, doing this, not from mere curiosity, but with some measure of sensual desire, are either already unchaste, or will become so before very long. St. Bernard tells us **[where?]** that if persons of different sexes take deliberate satisfaction in contemplating each other and yet no sinful desires arise within them, it is a more wonderful thing than if a dead man were to return to life.

Comment: You still didn't answer your own question? Lol

Comment: @Grasper I found it, reading St. Alphonsus! ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

St. Alphonsus of Liguori, [*Dignity & Duties of the Priest*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7683), pt. 2, instruction 2 "The Chastity of the Priest", II. "Means of Preserving Chastity":

> St. Bernard has written, that to be familiar with a woman and to preserve chastity require greater virtue than to raise a dead man to life.

It comes from a St. Bernard sermon on the Song of Songs ([*In Cant.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6545) [s. 65](https://books.google.com/books?id=b1I7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA396).):

> *Cum femina semper esse, et non cognoscere feminam, nonne plus est quam mortuum suscitare?*
> <sub>[lit.:] To always be with a woman, and not to know the woman, is this not greater than raising the dead?</sub>